# c++ when is baseconstructor executed?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Some questions regarding c++ inheritance:

In what order is the code of baseconstructors executed?

Is there a way to influence this order? (for example, other languages allow to place "super()" somewhere within the constructor)

Is it ok to access protected members of base classes in the constructor?

Comment: Add `std::cout` to each constructor and find out.

Comment: Is this your homework? Have you tried reading a book?

Comment: nope - trying to port some code that depends on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that class A has i base classes B_i, all of the B_i constructors are executed before any of the code for A's constructor is executed. The only exception is when you initialise a base class with a non-default constructor, but once they are run then all base classes are executed, and they have to go first in the initialiser list anyway. It is fine to access protected members of base classes because the base class is already constructed.

For example:

```
class A : public B, C {
  A()
  : B(1), //B and C are now constructed
    memberOfA(memberOfB)
  {
  }
};
```

If your member `memberOfA` needs something from B called `memberOfB` then that's fine because B is already constructed.

Comment: ok - so if the baseclasses are initialized with a non-default constructor, this non-default constructor code is executed after A's (non-default) constructor code?

Comment: The sentence about the "exception" is confusing to me, and I _think_ it is wrong.  Also, the order of parent class constructors in the initializer list is _irrelevant_ to the construction order.  They are constructed in the order that they are derived in the class' declaration.

Comment: @Mat the parent classes are initialized in the order they are declared in the class, and then members in the order they are declared in the class.  Then the class' constructor body is executed.  The initializer least tells _how_ to initialize, not _when_ (it does not affect the order, ever).

Comment: I didn't word that very well, I did mean what Mooing Duck said. I was including the base class initialisation in the bit where I said "the code for A's constructor", so then I said to say that they are in fact executed first and then got everyone confused.

Answer (score 1):

The order of construction is well defined in c++. Construction starts in the initialization list of the *complete* (most derived type), from which all other constructors are called. First the virtual bases, then the direct bases in the other of declaration (these will in trun apply the same order to construct their own bases and members) and finally the members, in the order of declaration in the class, not the order in which the constructors appear to be called in the initialization list.

There is no way to influence the order in which construction happens, and it is safe to access the base members within the construction of a derived type. What is probably surprising is, on the opposite direction, calling a virtual function from a base constructor. At each step of the construction process, the type of the object changes. That is, given an object of type X with bases B_i, only after all B_i subobjects have completed and right before the first member of X starts the type of the object becomes X. The implication of this is that calling a virtual method in a base class will be dispatched to that base class, and not to the final type being constructed.

Comment: "only after all B_i subobjects ... the type of the object becomes X" Not true. An object is of type `X` when it's constructor has *completed*. Not just constructed its bases and members, but also has executed the body of the constructor function itself. Until then, it isn't an `X` yet.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I don't think so. The standard states clearly that you can call virtual member functions in the constructor and *mem-initializer*s of data members and that the call will be dispatched to the class of the constructor being called. It also states that at that point *typeid* will return a *type_info* object referring to the type of the class that is currently being constructed. That really *looks* like at that particular point the type of the object is the type being constructed (12.7/4,5).

Comment: Well, consider this [GOTW about object construction and object lifetimes](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill13.htm). It seems to disagree.

Comment: @NicolBolas: If you are going to play your *Herb Sutter* card against my *Standard C++* card, you are probably going to loose the hand... :) Now a bit more serious, while the lifetime of the object for the whole program is bound to be from the completion of the constructor to the start of the destructor (i.e. no other code can use that object outside of that timespan), the object itself can, and the standard dictates at what point during construction and destruction the object behaves as an element of a given type.

Comment: ... beware: the fact that the object behaves as a given type does not mean that it can be used in all contexts as such, it is still undefined behavior to *use* any of the yet uninitialized members, but the type of the object being constructed **is** the type of the constructor for which the member data initializer or body is being executed. Note the important difference, until the *base* constructors don't complete, the object **is not** of the most derived type under any circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of the "parent"/super class is always called first. This is true recursively in case of multiple inheritance. (And that's one reason you really don't want virtual behaving constructors in C++ ;))
As for accessing members of the super class: It's perfectly fine, they are initialized.

Comment: Answer is mostly right, but implies that multiple inheritance is where "the superclass" is derived from a third class, instead of where the class in question inherits from several classes.